# cannot resolve Room dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to add the following dependencies to my project:

```
1.compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
2.annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

but my project Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0.
the following text show my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 27
 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.smm.room"
     minSdkVersion 17
     targetSdkVersion 27
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
 }
}

dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'

 compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
 annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: try to write `implementation` instead of `compile`.

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: corrected formatting of closing braces

Comment: @mehdi musavi you should update both dependencies to 1.1.1 check my answer and try this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update both to **1.1.1 version** like:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

Try the code below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smm.room"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
}
```

And your project grandle should be like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: @mehdi musavi is this help you?

Comment: I used this solution but showed me another error :Error:Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'. Received status code 503 from server: Forwarding failure

Comment: @mehdimusavi i update my code check again and be sure that your internet connection is available

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved by:

1.-uncheck the offline work in settings

2.- adding in `allprojects->repositories-> maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'` } .

3.- `repositories-> mavenCentral()`

4.- in dependencies like below :

```
def room_version = "1.1.1"

implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"

// optional - RxJava support for Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"

// optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:guava:$room_version"

// Test helpers
testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
```